# Does an @Input change trigger Angulars change detection?

Tags: angular

Currently I am reading guides and tutorials about Angulars change detection. There are some confusing statements. So please confirm or correct me.

The default Change Detection is triggered "every time an event triggers change detection (like user event, timer, XHR, promise and so on)." [1]

So this means it is NOT triggered when an @Input parameter changes. Is this correct?

Only if I use the On Push strategy the CD gets triggered if the @input reference changes.

[1] https://www.mokkapps.de/blog/the-last-guide-for-angular-change-detection-you-will-ever-need/

Comment: it will be triggered in case of Input is changed

Answer (score 2):

Further down the page in that blog post, it says [this](https://www.mokkapps.de/blog/the-last-guide-for-angular-change-detection-you-will-ever-need/#input-reference-changes):

> In the default change detection strategy, Angular will run the change detector any time @Input() data is changed or modified. Using the OnPush strategy, the change detector is only triggered if a new reference is passed as @Input() value.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe you could help me on this question as well: If I use the On Push strategy and a change occurs. Does Angular also compare all the values that are bound to the view? What I read was: on default change detection Angular compares the new values with the values bound to the view. And only if they change Angular re-renders the view. Does OnPush goes the same way after a change was recognized?

Comment: Yes if a change is recognised the view is re-rendered, regardless of whether it's from a change detected using the default or the OnPush strategy.